# How to run locally and execute the command NOT in container

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have a script `run_test.sh`. I need to run a script not in a container. But how can i run it if the script file is in the container? Also when i call this script it starts this container.
I have `windows` and `WSL ubuntu 22.04`

Comment: A container can't usually run commands on the host system.  The linked question has several workarounds, but they're quite involved.  If you have the image's original source, it might be easier to just run the script without involving Docker at all.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a Docker image that contains a script that you want to run directly on the host.

To do that, let's create a Dockerfile that creates an image with a script called `script.sh` like this

```
FROM debian
WORKDIR /app
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash' > script.sh && \
    echo 'echo ''Hello''' >> script.sh
```

You can the run the image, `cat` the script to stdout and pipe it into bash, like this

```
docker build -t test .
docker run --rm test cat script.sh | bash -
```

That will run the script on the host and print 'Hello'.